# Java Websockets + Event listeners. Is this the correct approach?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I'm currently creating a Java Web Application that will use Websockets. The server would be a Java class annotated with `@ServerEndpoint` called `Server.java` and the client would be a web browser so I'll most definitely access the Websocket endpoint using Javascript.

I need a Websocket because I want to notify the client(s) whenever something in the server changes. We have a utility class called the `EventManager` that manages all the events that happen in a subsystem. I plan to register `Server.java` as a dependent of `EventManager` so that whenever `EventManager` has something new, it will notify all of its dependents that this particular event happened.

Is this good practice? I thought about using AJAX/long polling but I believe to server-to-client behavior needs to be observed. And besides, there's no way for me to get the events in the database, I have to rely on the `EventManager` to notify my Websocket endpoint.

Example scenario that I want:

1. Client A connects to `Server.java`
2. Client B connects to `Server.java` (by now, there will be two sessions active)
3. `EventManager` detects an event and notifies all instances of `Server.java`.
4. `Server.java` sends a message to all active Websocket sessions.
5. Browser retrieves data sent through Websocket using Javascript and displays it.

I have been told to use Node.js for this but I am still pushing for a Java implementation since:

1. I have completely no experience with Node.js
2. Our `EventManager` class will be such a pain to convert into
   Javascript for Node.js

Comment: If you're looking for a Java answer, why would you tag this with node.js?  Us, node.js people can't help you one bit.

Comment: I just thought that some of you guys may have input as well. I wasn't really sure if my Java approach was completely valid and in that case, I might resort to Node.js as a worst case scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work the way you propose. A few pointers:

- Remove zombie Servers (Server.java) from your event manager.
- This will work fine with a single server machine, what happens with more? `Client A` and `Client B` may connect to different http processes.
- When a client refreshes a page you lose the connection
- You can use the fact that the ServerEndpoint can receive query params to pass state.
- Connections drop. Remember to implement a keep alive.
- You can only have one message encoder/decoder per websocket. Makes sense but requires a few ifs in the @OnMessage method.

Here is a [sample implementation](https://github.com/electronicarts/orbit/tree/master/samples/chat) of a chat server with multiple servers using websockets.

Comment: Yes, I will only be using one Server.java but wouldn't two difference Websocket connect requests create two different instances of Server.java?

Comment: Oh I got that - thanks for the input! Especially with the keep-alive part :)

Comment: And one last thing - you said to remove zombie Server.javas from the EventManager. Does this mean removing it from the list of dependents once a Websocket connection closes?

Comment: yes, make sure to remove all references to instances of `YourServer` after the connection is closed or lost.